# Angular 8 OIDC client - maximum call stack exceeded with authorize

Tags: angular, observable, openid-connect

We're using [this](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) oidc client for our angular frontend.

The application is meant to be in an iframe of another application (not in angular) - usually the user is already signed in to the sts so we want to try to authorize immediately to see if we need to do "proper" authorize or not.

Something funky happens though.

We're using the clients normal initialization in app module:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService, private oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService) {
    this.oidcConfigService.onConfigurationLoaded.subscribe((configResult: ConfigResult) => {
    // Use the configResult to set the configurations

    const config: OpenIdConfiguration = {
      stsServer: configResult.customConfig.stsServer,
      redirect_url: configResult.customConfig.redirect_url,
      client_id: configResult.customConfig.client_id,
      response_type: 'code',
      scope: "openid profile",
      silent_renew: true,
      silent_renew_url: 'https://localhost:4200/silent-renew.html',
      log_console_debug_active: true,
    };

    this.oidcSecurityService.setupModule(config, configResult.authWellknownEndpoints);
});

 }
}
```

Then in the app component we're immediately trying to authorize like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) { 
    if (this.oidcSecurityService.moduleSetup) {
      this.doCallbackLogicIfRequired();
  } else {
      this.oidcSecurityService.onModuleSetup.subscribe(() => {
          this.doCallbackLogicIfRequired();
      });
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.oidcSecurityService.getIsModuleSetup().subscribe(() => {
    this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth === false) {
        this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
      }
    })
  })
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {}

login() {
  this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
}

logout() {
  this.oidcSecurityService.logoff();
}

private doCallbackLogicIfRequired() {
  this.oidcSecurityService.authorizedCallbackWithCode(window.location.toString());
}
}
```

This results in authorize triggering, coming back to the application which tries to authorize again before oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized() has emitted any value which results in an endless loop resulting in maximum call stack exceeded.

However if we just introduce a long delay in the app component it starts to behave like you'd expect:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.oidcSecurityService.getIsModuleSetup().subscribe(() => {
    this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth === false) {
         setTimeout(() => {
           this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
         }, 10000);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

*Surely* we would see the same behavior as before just with a ten second delay but we don't. ***Why?*** Why does the timeout solve the issue? Are we going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Piping with distinctUntilChanged have solved the issue, although with that I can see that in the console that getIsAuthorized from the debug log of the library seems to emit two falses in a row - I guess that's what the crux was, don't know if that is the intended behavior.

```
this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth === false) {
           this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
      }
    });
```